# How can I get 'Bytes processed' and 'Bytes billed' when reading from Bigquery Storage API (python)

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm reading data from partitioned and clustered BigQuery table. The only way to get exactly the 'Bytes processed' value is to actually run the query.

Now if I'm reading the same data using python client library for `Storage API`, (taking setup from https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage/blob/master/samples/quickstart.py)
How can I get 'bytes processed' in this case?

Comment: Was your question answered?

Comment: The answer didn't answer the question. Your comment did however. Don't know how to mark it in this case.

Comment: I could post it as an answer so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, `BigQuery Storage API` and `BigQuery API` works differently.

As you can see in the API [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#readsession) for `BigQuery Storage API`, there is not such fields that hold the required information about bytes processed.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Bytes processed is measured when the storage API reads the column files. In your Java example you do that by invoking the storage API. In BQ this is only invoked when you run the query.

If you just edit the query in the console, BQ will give you an estimate only.

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to run the query to get the exact number. That's what I want. In BQ API I can see it in job information after it completes. What about storage API. Is this information available anywhere?

Comment: Apparently the BQ Storage API doesnt have this field in the response: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#readsession